# How to remove titlebar from noncsd-windows in wayland

Tags: c, gtk3, gnome-3, wayland

In source code of mutter, `/src/core/window.c`, has a very nice string

`window->mwm_border_only = FALSE;`

If change value to `TRUE`, mutter removes titlebar, just leaving borders, allowing you to resize the window. But this fully works only in X-session.

In wayland-session, titlebars remove for windows of Firefox, Viewnior, Geany etc., but not removed for Bluefish, Pamac, Quodlibet...

http://storage8.static.itmages.ru/i/16/0417/h_1460873488_5752646_bf0ef083c9.png

Why? How to fix it? What are differences for windows of this applications in the source code Mutter or Wayland?

Distribution Linux Arch-based - Antergos.

Thanks you.

P.S. I beg excuse me for my english.